# Javascript and Return Function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am working on a lab for school and having a hard time getting a return value from another function. I think I am just missing one thing and cannot figure it out. The function is called from an HTML document and depending on the number inputted will return the letter grade. Below is my code:

```
function submitGradeForconversion() {
  
  var numGradeElement = document.getElementById("numGrade");
  var numGrade = Math.round(numGradeElement.value);

  if (numGrade >= 0 && numGrade <= 100) {
    document.getElementById("letterGrade").innerHTML = convertGrade(numGrade);
  } else {
    alert("Please enter a number between 0 and 100!")
  }
}

function convertGrade(numGrade) {

  if (numGrade >= 95) {
  return numGrade(A);
  } 
}
```

The HTML is just a basic input box with a button to call the first function. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `numGrade` isn't a function that can be called.

Comment: You are not returning when `numGrade` is less than 95

Comment: You'll want to `return "A";` instead of `return numGrade(A);`. And you'll want to add code to cover for "B", "C", ...etc.

Comment: Yup, just needed return "A"; and it worked like a charm. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function submitGradeForconversion() {
  
  var numGradeElement = document.getElementById("numGrade");
  var numGrade = Math.round(numGradeElement.value);

  if (numGrade >= 0 && numGrade <= 100) {
    document.getElementById("letterGrade").innerHTML = convertGrade(numGrade);
  } else {
    alert("Please enter a number between 0 and 100!")
  }
}

function convertGrade(numGrade) {

  if (numGrade >= 95) {
    return "A";
  } 
   if (numGrade >= 75) {
    return "B";
  } 
   if (numGrade >= 55) {
    return "C";
  } 
   if (numGrade >= 35) {
    return "D";
  } 
   if (numGrade >= 15) {
    return "E";
  } else{
   return "F";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="numGrade" onChange="submitGradeForconversion()" />

<div id="letterGrade">X</div>
```